# " length of 'dimnames' [2] not equal to array extent" error when using nlsLM function

Tags: r, nls

I am trying to use the `nlsLM` function from the `minpack.lm` package in R.

I want to estimate parameters `kd` and `mu` in this model equation.

```
h.mod <- P.cal.norm ~ P0*(1 - exp(-(B/(kd*Time.cal))^mu))
```

And these are my start values:

```
bounds0 <- list(kd = c(1/3000, 1/2000), mu = c(1, 10))
```

I construct the data frame using these

```
Time.cal <-  c(0, 1000, 2000, 2500, 2750, 3000, 3250, 3500, 3750, 4000, 5000)
P.cal.norm <- c(1.0, 0.99, 0.98, 0.95, 0.795, 0.59, 0.35, 0.295, 0.175, 0.14, 0.095)
dataset = data.frame(Time.cal,P.cal.norm)
```

And this is how I structured my `nlsLM` model

```
h.mod0.fit2 <- nlsLM(h.mod, data = dataset, start = bounds0, algorithm = 'LM')
```

The error I get is

> Error in dimnames(x) <- dn :
> length of 'dimnames' [2] not equal to array extent
> In addition: There were 50 or more warnings (use warnings() to see the first 50)

When type `warnings()` I get 50 lines of this:

> Warning messages:
> 1: In kd * Time.cal :
> longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length

What I can do to solve this error? Thanks.

Here the whole code is given:

```
library(rcompanion)
library(nlstools)
library(minpack.lm)

P0 <- 1.0 
B <- 1

Time.cal <-  c(0, 1000, 2000, 2500, 2750, 3000, 3250, 3500, 3750, 4000, 5000)
P.cal.norm <- c(1.0, 0.99, 0.98, 0.95, 0.795, 0.59, 0.35, 0.295, 0.175, 0.14, 0.095)

phys.mods <- function(Time, Temp) {
  k.h <- A.h*(RH.eff)^n*exp(-Ea.h/((Temp+273.15)*8.62e-5))
  P.Time <- P0*(1 - exp(-(B/(k.h*Time))^mu))
  t.f <- B/(k.h*(abs(log(0.2)))^(1/mu))
  res <- list("k.h" = k.h, "P.Time" = P.Time, "t.f" = t.f)
  return(res)
}

h.mod <- P.cal.norm ~ P0*(1 - exp(-(B/(kd*Time.cal))^mu))
bounds0 <- data.frame(kd = c(1/3000, 1/2000), mu = c(1, 10))
h.mod0.fit <- nlsLM(h.mod, data = data.frame(Time.cal, P.cal.norm), start = bounds0, algorithm = "LM")
```

Comment: I specified P0 and B above with the all of the code.